# illegally attempted to associate a proxy with two open Sessions while calling session.save()

Tags: java, hibernate, bulkinsert, hibernate-criteria

I'm trying to save bulk data in to the table
while saving I'm facing the issue like

**illegally attempted to associate a proxy with two open Sessions**

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();

        for (Object obj : ObjectList) {
            session.save(obj );
        }
        transaction.commit();
        session.close();
     }
```

I saw this issue while updating the records but now it is getting for save is there any solution.

Comment: This issue is occuring when I'm trying to insert data more than 5000 records that is also in rear cases only in Production server.

Comment: You need to put your whole method here. The exception you reported is most likely not just because of the `save()`! Can you put your lines above `openSession()`

Answer (score 1):

**Here you can flush a batch of inserts and release memory:**

for more information you can refer hibernate doc on [batch processing.](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#batch)

```
    int count=0;

     for (Object obj : ObjectList) {

         session.save(obj );
         //20, same as default the JDBC batch size
         if ( ++count % 20 == 0 ) {
             session.flush();
             session.clear();
         }
    }
    transaction.commit();
    session.close();
```

Comment: Thanks for reply But I have already tried this still i didn't get the issue in dev environment

Comment: try updating your batch size in configuration.xml 
`<property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">30</property>`

Comment: I have already given 50 for batch_size  in configuration table and in database it is 300

Comment: So did you change `count % 20` to `count % 50` ??

Comment: Okay I will try